# PySpark Add Months to Date Field Based on vlaue of column

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with a date column and an integer column and I'd like to add months based on the integer column to the date column.  I tried the following, but I'm getting an error:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
withColumn('future', f.add_months('cohort', col('period')))
```

Where 'cohort' is my date column and `period` is an integer.  I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: Column is not iterable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `expr` to pass a column as second parameter for `add_months` function:

```py
df.withColumn('future', F.expr("add_months(cohort, period)"))
```

Comment: Do you know if this is doable with spark.sql.functions?

Comment: @BrendanA No, it's not possible at the moment. The dataframe API function can only take an int for `months` param.

Comment: why we cannot do df.withColumn('future', F.expr("add_months(cohort, col('period'))"))? col is a spark sql function but it reports error